# Elliptical radial gradient in CGContext?

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext

As far as I can tell you can use two methods to draw gradients in a `CGContext`, that's `drawLinearGradient` and `drawRadialGradient`. What I'm looking for is a way to define an elliptical gradient where I can define `x` and `y` radii.

An example of this capability in another environment (`SVG`).

```
<RadialGradient id="gradient" cx="50" cy="50" rx="20" ry="40" fx="150" fy="75">
```

The existing declaration for `drawRadialGradient` is as follows.

```
func drawRadialGradient(_ gradient: CGGradient, 
            startCenter: CGPoint, 
            startRadius: CGFloat, 
              endCenter: CGPoint, 
              endRadius: CGFloat, 
                options: CGGradientDrawingOptions)
```

Both start and end radii are scalar values, so all you can do is circles. How can I draw elliptical gradients in a `CGContext`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to scale the context and use CGContextDrawRadialGradient().  If you scale down, there should be no artifacts.  Does the following work?

```
CGContextRef context;
CGGradientRef gradient;
CGGradientDrawingOptions options;
CGPoint center;
CGFloat radiusX;
CGFloat radiusY;

CGFloat radius = MAX(radiusX, radiusY);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
// scale down by the smaller dimension, and translate so the center stays in place
if (radiusX < radiusY) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, center.x - (center.x * (radiusX / radiusY)), 0);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, radiusX / radiusY, 1.0);
}
else {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, center.y - (center.y * (radiusY / radiusX)));
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, radiusY / radiusX);
}
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 0, center, radius, options);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Incidentally, I think this is roughly the behavior if you set the `type` property of `CAGradientLayer` to the undocumented and private value of `@"radial"`.  It uses the startPoint as the center, and the difference of the startPoint and endPoint to determine the radiusX and radiusY values (i.e. the endPoint defines a corner of the bounding box of the gradient, and the startPoint is the center).  It does have odd behavior when you make the start and end point nearly the same, so there is probably more going on there than I have figured out (and probably why Apple never bothered to make it public).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be to apply a scale transform with unequal x and y scale factors to your context before drawing the gradient. That would stretch it out of round, and should make it oval.

Comment: Scaling in terms of a transform is a non-option because it adds artifacts.

Comment: How about rendering it at an increased size and then scaling it down?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "royal road". This facility is not built-in so you'll have to draw every pixel yourself. (There are probably third-party libraries that will do that for you.)